# Skip password prompt and pass password to ssh-add in script

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to write a script that automatically unlocks all of my rsa keys with `ssh-add` on Arch Linux.

I use `pass` to store my passwords (encrypted with gpg keys) and I'm trying to pass its input to `ssh-add` as follows:

```
rsa_dir=~/.ssh
cd $rsa_dir
ls -1 id_rsa* |
grep -v '.pub' |
while read file; do
  # example: file == id_rsa_github -> keyname == rsa/github
  key_name=${file/id_rsa_/rsa/}
  # pass will prompt (only once) for the master password, then print out the request password to stdout
  pass $key_name | ssh-add $file
done
```

However, it gives an error:

```
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/lib/ssh/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
```

But if I just run `ssh-add $file`, it prompts for a password and works fine. I don't want to use the default ssh-askpass to get the password. I need to use my own script.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: This won't fix the issue you're having, but it is far safer and better to use `for file in id_rsa*` instead of `ls | while`.

Comment: @terdon, the drawback with the `for` approach is that it will take both `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` files. This approach requires adding a `if` statement to skip the loop for the `id_rsa.pub`

Comment: `find $rsa_dir ! -iregex '.*\.pub$'-print0 | xargs -0 ...` or `| while read file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was in the same boat as you, so i found two method to do this:

## Using xclip

```bsh
pass yourpassword | xclip -selection clipboard ; ssh-add yourprivatekey
```

then you just use whatever key you would normally use to paste your password. Bear in mind this use the *clipboard*, so your password may be noticed by third party if you're not the only user/if you're on untrusted network...

## Using Expect

```bsh
PASS=`pass yourpassword`
/usr/bin/expect <<EOF
set timeout -1
spawn ssh-add privatekey
match_max 100000
expect -exact "Enter passphrase for ~/.ssh/privatekey: "
send -- "$PASS\r"
expect eof
EOF
```

Should work. Feel free to change the path to your privatekey above, or use `autoexpect` on a script which have `ssh-add yourprivatekey` to generate a somewhat working script...

## Other idea(s)

The following is what i didn't test or managed to make it work:

- You could use `screen` or `tmux`, which have some ways to send keys to a running session...
- You could use some command that send your keys, which could be beneficial for the `xclip` method above. `sendkey` on [github](https://github.com/kyoto/sendkeys) and `xdotool` come to mind.

Comment: The solution using `expect` sounds interesting (the program itself seems interesting). I will try that out

Comment: That did not work :( . It showed a prompt for every rsa key and kept waiting for me to insert the password. I'm looking for a way to avoid any manual operation (such as typing the password or pasting it from the clipboard manually)

Comment: Update: The reason why it wasn't working is because I was doing `send -- "$password"`, but this sends the password without "pressing enter". I changed it to `send -- "$password\r"` it worked! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this; forgot to add a `\r` as i usually do when using `expect` ...Edited. @blackyellow